# mariadb docker container on OS X: can't create database directory

Tags: macos, docker, mariadb, docker-compose

I've trouble with mariadb on OSX, I did same on CentOS and it works fine. So it must be OSX issue:

```
mariadb:
  image: mariadb:latest
  container_name: mariadb
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: XXXXXXXX
  volumes:
    - /Users/sandro/Code/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

logs contain following error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql': Permission denied
Fatal error Can't create database directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql'
```

if I let it mount inside container like so:

```
volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
```

it works but I've persistence issues, once vm is restarted dbs are gone.

I tried to create mysql dir and give it world writable permissions and received following error instead:

```
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.14-MariaDB-1~jessie) starting as process 1 ...
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] InnoDB: ./ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write mode
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] mysqld: File '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' not found (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't open file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-05-20 23:43:54 140694234605504 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the mysql container run as the user 1000.

In Dockerfile:

```
USER "1000"
```

In docker-compose.yml

```
db:
   image: mysql
   user: "1000"
```

This is my current workaround worked (did via docker-compose.yml). The 1000 user is -I believe- the default user for files in docker volumes (at least for docker-machine), so this should let you write to the volume.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, I'd been searching for a solution for this myself so wanted to share. Updated to be more answer-like.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's permission issue.  On Mac docker runs in virtual box that maps the local directories through VM.  It's tricky to get permissions right.  First try setting the least restrictive permissions on your /Users/sandro/Code directory.  Also try to pre-create /Users/sandro/Code/myssql directory and give it world writeable permissions before starting your container.

**UPDATE**: So the issue is actually more complicated.  Looks like you can't do many low-level file calls unless the user id inside of the container matches the  id of the user who started the docker machine.  Here are some links that clarify this issue:

https://www.bountysource.com/issues/5393565-1-3-0-only-root-can-write-to-osx-volumes-can-t-change-permissions-within

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/581

The issue is between boot2docker,  MariaDB image start-up script, docker-compose and Virtual Box guest operating system

I was able to run maria db container by doing this

```
mkdir mysql
chmod ug+ws mysql
docker run -it -u $UID:$UID -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bob \
         -v /Users/vlad/Proj/Stack/maria/mysql:/var/lib/mysql \
         mariadb:latest
```

Note that the -u option

Comment: Hi, I pre-created mysql dir and changed perms to `o+w` got the error, I reported it in OP.

Comment: @salivan did some more digging around... see updated answer

Comment: hey, thanks for your help. unfortunately it didn't work for me either... db was still failing. So I just switched to docker beta that has better permission handling and overall better OSX integration.

Answer (score 1):

The path looks weird in the error message:
`mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql': Permission denied`

For me it looks like the mariadb image is appending /mysql on the volume path. By removing `/mysql` in the docker-compose.yml file it worked like a charm.

```
mdb:
  image: mariadb
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib
```